# Is it permitted to trim cheekbone hair?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, payot-sideburns

Is it permitted to trim cheekbone hair?
I know someone who has a hairy temple which the hair extends towards his upper cheekbones. I would think not because it's above the peyos bone, but I really don't know. What's the Sephardi halachah?

Something like this:
http://images.yuku.com.s3.amazonaws.com/image/jpg/85516465862e4adc82b3e1265794833cf38fdb5d_r.jpg

The person wants to use number 1 and trim.

Comment: Note: when U.S. barbers say "number 1", they mean an eighth of an inch. If that's what you mean also, you should probably say so, since I doubt it's a universal convention (and, even stateside, I doubt everyone knows it).

Answer (score -2):

I think that is one of the five places that the torah forbids.
And in genaral the tzemach Tzedek writes that it is assur min hatora to even trim

Comment: Everything in this post is wrong AFAICT. There are 7 spots the Torah forbids, and the TzTz thought trimming (as opposed to shaving) is a Derabanan IINM.

Comment: @DoubleAA ... Plus, the answer's first sentence sounds like it refers to a prohibition even on trimming, with the second extending prohibition that beyond the five spots.